# How to add a separate CSS file for each view in ejs

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am want to add a separate CSS file for each view in ejs

this is my project tree:

```
My-App
├─ app.js
├─ package-lock.json
├─ package.json
├─ public
│  └─ css
│     └─ style.css
└─ views
   ├─ header.ejs
   ├─ view1.ejs
   ├─ view2.ejs
   ├─ view3.ejs
   └─ footer.ejs
```

All of these views are styled by only one file which is **style.css**.
I link this CSS file in **header.ejs** as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <title>XXXXXX</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main-container">
    <div class="left-menu">

        <form action="/" method="post">
        <div class="left-menu-list">

            <button class="btn" name="leftBtn" value="XXX1" type="submit">XXX</button>

            <button class="btn" name="leftBtn" value="XXX2" type="submit">XXX</button>

            <button class="btn" name="leftBtn" value="XXX3" type="submit">XXX</button>

            <button class="btn" name="leftBtn" value="XXX4" type="submit">XXX</button>

        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
```

and of course in each view I do the following

```
<%- include("header") -%>

<!-- the view content -->

<%- include("footer") -%>
```

what I do want is to do something like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/view1Style.css" type="text/css">` in each view file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using two partials, use three. Put all similar body code in another partial.

```
//menu.ejs

<div class="main-container">
    <div class="left-menu">

        <form action="/" method="post">
        <div class="left-menu-list">

            <button class="btn" name="leftBtn" value="XXX1" type="submit">XXX</button>

            <button class="btn" name="leftBtn" value="XXX2" type="submit">XXX</button>

            <button class="btn" name="leftBtn" value="XXX3" type="submit">XXX</button>

            <button class="btn" name="leftBtn" value="XXX4" type="submit">XXX</button>

        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Then change other view structure like this:

```
  <%- include("header.ejs") -%>
  <!-- Add your separate css files here -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/view1Style.css" type="text/css">
 </head>

 <body>
   <%- include("menu.ejs") -%>
   <!-- the view content -->
   <%- include("footer.ejs") -%>
   <!-- You can also add separate script files here -->
 </body>
</html>
```